# How can i control Age group in Axis in power BI Chart?

Tags: powerbi

I have age group in X-axis how i can control to display orderly from low to high for example <30, 30-40, 40-50, 50-60, 60-70, 70-80, 80-90. based on the picture. it's displayed out of order.

[image]

Comment: Create a new column from 1 to 8 from different age group. Then use age_group in the axis, but in the data model, apply order by on age_group column using that other created Order column.

Comment: i am new in power bi can you give me small sample file. Thank you

Comment: You can provide your power bi file with small set of sample data (not real data).